# Netlify 'build.command failed: base: /opt/build/repo/client' for deploying React app

Tags: reactjs, deployment, netlify, build-error

I'm trying to deploy a React app to Netlify but in the deployment process I'm running into the following error:

```
...
9:11:17 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
9:11:17 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
9:11:17 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
9:11:17 AM: ​
9:11:17 AM:   Error message
9:11:17 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
9:11:17 AM: ​
9:11:17 AM:   Error location
9:11:17 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
9:11:17 AM:   npm run build
9:11:17 AM: ​
9:11:17 AM:   Resolved config
9:11:17 AM:   build:
9:11:17 AM:     base: /opt/build/repo/client
9:11:17 AM:     command: npm run build
9:11:17 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
9:11:17 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/client/build
9:11:17 AM:     publishOrigin: ui
9:11:18 AM: Caching artifacts
9:11:18 AM: Started saving node modules
...
```

Keep in mind I am answering this question myself as I have found a solution and want to share it with anyone else who might run into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old but I found a solution that solves it and thought I'd provide it in case someone else with a broken build stops by.

In order to build Next.js on Netlify you need to have the Netlify Next.js plugin installed. You can do that by creating a `netlify.toml` file in the root of your project:

```
[[plugins]]
package = "@netlify/plugin-nextjs"

[build]
publish = ".next"
```

My scripts in the `package.json` look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

My Netlify settings look like this:

[image]

The main thing to note is the following:

- You must use the Netlify Next.js plugin which needs to be added to your project dependencies
- Publish directory must be specified on Netlify to `.next`, which is the default directory when running `next build`
- You must run `next build` on Netlify so that the `.next` directory gets generated. I've done so by running `npm run build` which is pointing to `next build`.

Hopefully this helps anybody having this same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is a problem with the `npm run build` command that Netlify executes in the deployment process although, when running `npm run build` locally it is successful.

Therefore just removing the build step from the Netlify Continuous Deployment tab fixed the problem through bypassing the Netlify build process and just relying on the locally generated `/build` folder as the Publish directory in the Netlify build settings.

Here's a screenshot for reference:
[image]